# Check if node exists

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, exists

I am working with IronPython 2.7 in Dynamo. I need to check if a node exists. If so, the text in the node should be written to a list. If no, then False should be written to the list.

I get no error. But, even if a node exists in the list, it doesn't write the text in the list. False is correctly written into the list.

Simple Example:

```
<note>
    <note2>
        <yolo>
            <to>
                <type>
                    <game>
                        <name>Jani</name>
                        <lvl>111111</lvl>
                        <fun>2222222</fun>
                    </game>
                </type>
            </to>
            <mo>
                <type>
                    <game>
                        <name>Bani</name>
                        <fun>44444444</fun>
                    </game>
                </type>
            </mo>
        </yolo>
    </note2>
</note>
```

So, the node `lvl` is only in the first node `game`. I expect the resulting list like `list[11111, false]`.

Here is my code:

```
import clr
import sys

clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib")
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml="note.xml"

main_xpath=".//game"
searchforxpath =".//lvl"

list=[]

tree = ET.parse(xml)
root = tree.getroot()

main_match = root.findall(main_xpath)

for elem in main_match:
if elem.find(searchforxpath) is not None:
    list.append(elem.text)  
else:
    list.append(False)

print  list
```

Why is the list empty where the string should be? I get `list[ ,false]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the text of the match from the elem.find, not the original elem:

```
 for elem in main_match:
    subelem = elem.find(searchforxpath)
    if subelem != None:
        list.append(subelem.text)  
    else:
        list.append(False)
```

Comment: Thx for your help! This is exactly what i needed:)